# preg_replace based on conditional logic in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace

I have a large an array and some value by default saved in db.i wanted to extract all data in excel/ CSV.

```
echo '<pre>'
$third_guest_array=[
  'add_3rd_guest?'  // this is radio button if user select "No" options then their salutation must be blank in excel or csv. without update in database
       ];
if(in_array($value,$third_guest_array)){

                    if($value=='No') { 
                         $default_array_value=[
                                 'third_guest_salutation',  // this field value by default store salutation e.g Mr,Dr in db
                                ];
                    $value=in_array($field,$default_array_value);
                       #$value = preg_replace('/\bDr\b/', '', in_array($value,$default_array_value));
                       $value = preg_replace('/\bDr\b/', '',$value);
                    }
                }
```

But I am getting a this output

[image: This gives me the following result:]

Below is my desired result:

[image: Below is my desired result]

Comment: The data in both pictures is identical. Please **explain** what you want to achieve and the difference with the current result, and/or provide a sample dataset.

Comment: @Calimero if add_3rd_guest?==No then third_guest_salutation must be empty(blank) in a excel sheet.

Comment: @Calimero yes both picture are identical but third_guest_salutation  value are not identical.

Comment: @Calimero if add_3rd_guest?==No then third_guest_salutation must be empty(blank) in a excel sheet. yes both picture are identical but third_guest_salutation value are not identical

Comment: Your code is honestly painful to read and test as it is. Maybe if you provide a sample of CSV data, somebody will be more likely to help you with it.

Comment: One thing is for sure : the return value of `in_array()` is a boolean, you don't want to overwrite `$value` with it (line 11 in the above code)